# What's the best way to implement writing blog posts in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2

We need to have a way to write posts for SEO. We would want it to be as future proof as possible.

Answer (score 0):

There are several modules which can add blog functionality in Magento

However I would recommend having a WordPress for that. Magento is great as e-commerce & WordPress is great as blog. Just let every application do what it does better

For instance you can place a WordPress under some subdomain and then search for some integration modules so you can lead traffic from WordPress to Magento

Comment: Wouldn't adding Wordpress to an already built Magento site be more complicated? We wanted it to be just Magento only environment to make it easier.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 popular solutions for implementing blog in Magento 2:

1. Use a `Magento 2 extension` (module) for blog:
   There are some extensions available both paid and free. I'll list some free extensions which are popular here:

- Mageplaza Magento 2 Blog Extension: https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-better-blog/
  Github link: https://github.com/mageplaza/magento-2-blog
- Magefan Magento 2 Blog Extension: https://magefan.com/magento2-blog-extension

2. Use `Wordpress` for blog, here you integrate Wordpress into Magento 2.
   There is a free popular Magento extension support that: Fishpig WordPress
   Github link: https://github.com/bentideswell/magento2-wordpress-integration. You can visit this link to find read more about the extension and installation guide.